# Qml canvas 2d no line to be displayed

Tags: canvas, qml

Here is a code snipped where I'm trying to draw a cross line on canvas

```
function drawAxis(context)
{
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

    context.beginPath();

    // draw axis
    context.moveTo(0, center_h);
    context.lineTo(width, center_h);
    context.moveTo(center_w, 0);
    context.lineTo(center_w, height);
    context.closePath();
}
```

But nothing is displayed in fact. What could be a problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the lines are not painted if the [`stroke()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#stroke-method) function is not called. Thus, the final working code is the following:

```
function drawAxis(context) {
    context.lineWidth = 1
    context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(0, center_h)
    context.lineTo(width, center_h)
    context.moveTo(center_w, 0)
    context.lineTo(center_w, height)
    context.closePath()
    context.stroke()                      // <--- lines are drawn here!
}
```

Comment: What a fun hour figuring this out was. Thanks.